# Interpretation of Model When Intentionally Excluding a Control Variable!

Tags: interpretation, binary-data, controlling-for-a-variable

I am looking at factors affecting firm value (the dependent variable).  I fitted the following model using OLS:

$log(FirmValue_i)=\beta_0 + \beta_1Divers_i+ \beta_2HQLoc_i + \epsilon_i$

where $Divers$ is the diversification discount and $HQLoc$ is the location of corporate headquarter. I also controlled for R&D expenditure, a proxy measure of information asymmetry, in my model. When I exclude R&D, the coefficient for diversification discount is 7.5% and the coefficient for NYC is 5%. When I include R&D the coefficient on diversification discount drops to 2% and the coefficient of NYC drops to 1%.

I know this means that it is actually R&D that affects firm value rather than diversification but is it correct for me to say, "R&D as proxy for information asymmetry clearly has an important effect on the dependent variable excess value. However, in the models in which we don’t control for R&D and thus for information asymmetry, the effect of location is more pronounced. This confirms the hypothesis that when there is higher information asymmetry, such as in diversified firms with complex structures, the location is more important?"

Comment: I'm confused over your use of percentages for your coefficients.  Are these expressed as marginal effects?  What kind of regression model did you run? OLS? Logit?

Comment: I'm sorry. My dependent variable is log - that's why I interpret the coefficients as %. I did an OLS regression!

Comment: Thanks so much for editing! I also added some control variables in the regression (e.g. profitability, leverage, etc.) but this is fine to understand the main idea!

Comment: Is $\beta_{RandD}$ statistically significant?  How does the significance of the other coefficients change when you add $RandD$ into the model?

Comment: The beta of R&D is always significant, so it is definitely an important control variable, but it greatly reduces my sample size (by 50%) - that's why I always run one regression with R&D & one without. I only have about 1000 diversified firms in my sample, so reducing it by 50% is not good. The significance level of the multi-segment indicator (= 1 if the firm has more than one segment, 0 otherwise) to determine the diversification discount remains significant at 1%. Unfortunately my location variables (NYC) are never significant. I still interpret them though, since its the topic of my paper

Comment: Is there a way for you to impute R&D?  It appears you have problems with missing value, which would bias your results if your estimation was done only on 50% of the original sample.  A simple "workaround" is to recode R&D = missing to 0 and create a binary flag called "R&D missing" that takes on a value of 1 if R&D was = missing in the original variable and 0 otherwise.  This is not an ideal solution, as you are making the assumption that all observations missing a value on R&D are homogenous, but it *is* a way for you to retain sample size.

Comment: Could it be that losing the observations through adding R&D is causing the change in the coefficients rather than the actual effect of R&D on the other variables? Many firms don't report R&D, so by adding R&D as a control variable I eliminate all the ones that don't report it from the analysis (I think). Maybe the firms that report R&D also have less of a discount, so when we control for R&D we only still have the firms in the sample which have a lower discount anyway. New to regressions and such ;) Thanks so much @marquisdecarabas!!

Comment: Some kind of imputation is in order, but even the experts are divided on the best method.  Multiple imputation (MI) is pretty hot right now, and you can read more info on MI in Rubin and Little (2002)'s *Statistical analysis with missing data*.  Perhaps simple imputation is OK too (taking medians at some level of aggregation, for example), but then you'd probably need to adjust your standard errors if you do that...

Comment: Yes, it is possible that changes in coefficient was because the regression was run on the sub-sample not missing on R&D.  You can fit your original model (all variables except R&D, "Model B") restricted to those not missing R&D and fit the second model (all variables, including R&D, "Model C") and compare the coefficients from the model without R&D done on the full sample ("Model A") to coefficients on both Models B and C to see whether the sample conditional on R&D ≠ missing differs from the models done on the full sample or not.  I still maintain that you should do something about your

Comment: missing values, because as I said above, doing the analysis conditional on R&D not missing will give you biased results, especially if the factors associated with R&D being missing is associated with your outcome of interest

Comment: I am doing it in Stata right away!! Thank you so much!! I might write you again if something goes wrong on the way. You really helped me a lot - I appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks again @marquisdecarabas! My results really change a lot when I use the conditional effect. Since you seem like an expert in the field, I have one additional small question: as you know I have HQ location as my independent variable. However, I use city in one regression and in another I use state. Of course city is implicitly included in state and the effect for state tends to be larger, can I legitimately say that state is the driving source? I read about multi-level models, but that's too difficult for me, so I won't include both in one regression but I still want to give a conclusion!

Comment: @marquisdecarabas - sorry for bothering you again! I used the "workaround" method you suggested above (recoding . to 0 for missing R&D values). How could I explain why I did this? THANKS!

Comment: "Can I legitimately say that state is the driving source?"  It depends on what theoretical angle you are working from.  For instance, if you're thinking about local markets/market shares, then state may be too broad, especially if you have firms in large metropolitan areas and smaller cities.  If you are trying to play the "state policy" angle (I do research in health policy, so this scenario is plausible in my case), then state would be appropriate.  I'm not familiar with your topic, so I can't comment on whether state or city would be appropriate in your case